# How can I see which Google account WhatsApp is using for its backing up?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

How can I see which Google account WhatsApp is using for its backing up?

For example, I have various Google accounts on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the WhatsApp app, go to Settings - Chats - Chat backup. Under "Google Drive settings", there is "Google Account" entry that shows the current Google account used to backup.

It is also possible to change the Google account from there. From [WhatsApp FAQ - How to back up to Google Drive](https://faq.whatsapp.com/744445782709185/)

> #### Change the account you want to use for backups
>
> 1. Open WhatsApp.
> 2. Tap More options > Settings > Chats > Chat backup > Google Account.
> 3. Select the Google account you’d like to back up your chat history to.
>
> Note: If you change your Google account, you’ll lose access to any backups saved in that account.